# PHP mysql_query returing 0 results even though it should be 450

Tags: php, android, mysql

PHP script running server side to handle queries from Java application. The table has 450 results that should be returned but for some reason its going to the no businesses found statement..

For testing im sending the information on the HTTPGet from the android app with the following vals

varQuery2 is a String and = state
 varQuery1 is a String and = MS

```
<?php

$result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM businessdata WHERE '" 
. mysql_real_escape_string($_REQUEST['varQuery2'])."' =  '" 
. mysql_real_escape_string($_REQUEST['varQuery1'])."'") or die(mysql_error());

// check for empty result
if (mysql_num_rows($result) > 0) {
// looping through all results
// businesses node
$response["businesses"] = array();

while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) {
    // temp user array
$business = array();
$business["bid"] = $row["idbusinessData"];
$business["name"] = $row["name"];
$business["owner"] = $row["owner"];
$business["phone_main"] = $row["phone_main"];



array_push($response["businesses"], $business);
}
// success
$response["success"] = 1;

// echoing JSON response
echo json_encode($response);
} else {
// no businesses found
$response["success"] = 0;
$response["message"] = "No businesses found";

// echo no users JSON
echo json_encode($response);
}
?>
```

Why is this failing and any ideas how to fix it? Also please note that the entire script worked with static state = 'MS' in the select... Even when I call it from a browser window with:

```
http://address/scriptName.php?varQuery2=state+varQuery1=MS
```

I still get the same No Business Found response..

As per comments the below is the table that is being used here..

```
CREATE  TABLE `test`.`businessData` (
`idbusinessData` INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT ,
`name` CHAR(255) NULL ,
`owner` CHAR(255) NULL ,
`phone_main` CHAR(10) NULL ,
PRIMARY KEY (`idbusinessData`) );
```

Just a little update to see if I am on the right track:

```
switch ($_GET){
case "state":
$result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM businessdata WHERE state =  '" . mysql_real_escape_string($_REQUEST['varQuery1'])."'") or die(mysql_error());

case "zip";
// zipcode results
case "nothing";
// default results
}
```

Comment: Without any information about the table, we cannot answer your question...

Comment: You should be using [prepared statements](http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.prepared-statements.php) in any new PHP code - the old `mysql_query` methods have been deprecated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are trying to select every business for which `"state" = "MS"`, which will of course be false every time (you compare the two *strings* against each other).

You should avoid having column names as part of your GET request. Instead, consider using a specific GET field for each column which you'd want to query (e.g. `search.php?state=MS`), then building the query based on the supplied parameters.

Comment: Thanks much... Im guessing that I would have use $_GET(varCol) then do what ever the PHP select Case equivalent is, then lastly do my query inside of there..  Sound about right??

Comment: I added a code block above that seems like it is on the right track... Do I need to change anything with it??

Comment: Actually, better to do `if(isset($_GET['state'])) mysql_query...` and chain those together. If you have another question about this later, you can always ask another...